# C++ array row average

Tags: c++, arrays, row, average, rows

I need to find the average of every row below central array diagonal.

[image]

Highlighted numbers are the ones I need to count. First row sum below the purple central diagonal is equal to 4, second row sum is equal to 15 and so on.

I'm stuck on finding the average of the sums for each row.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double A[100][100];
    double B[100];
    double n,m,sk;
    double vid=0;

    cin >> n >> m;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            if( j<i && A[i][j]>0) {
                cout << i << "-" <<A[i][j]<<  endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lets skip the diagonal part for a while, do you know how to calculate the average of a whole row? Start with that.

Comment: Tip: you can free tools such as AStyle to format you code. That's what I used now. Please do always format your code before posting it (if you keep it always formatted you'll discover that that saves you work).

Comment: I'm kind of stuck at counting the row average. Not quite sure how to split rows from the whole array.

Comment: There is no need to split any rows.  What does your second nested `for` loop do?

Comment: Also, why are `n` and `m` of type `double`?

Comment: I tried to display in which row the needed elements are. For example 4 is in 2nd row and 7 and 8 are in 3rd row. The i represents the row number while A[i][j] displays the element. Now im not sure how to calculate each rows average and print all the averages.

Comment: for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
   for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
      //calculate average here

I hope this helps you further.

Comment: Its my bad, its 6in the morning, and I think I was changing some variables and the double got mixed in. I'll use int.

Comment: Hint: The outer loop is for *rows*, the inner (nested) loop is for the columns of each row. Try adding all the values in a single row together and display it. Then do the same for the next row, etc.

Comment: @MatasSkaržauskas -- Take another step back -- how would you calculate the average of a single, 1 dimensional array of values?  How would that look any different than a 2d array, since each "row" in a 2D array is a 1D array?  The only difference is that you would be looping on each row, and in each loop calculating the 1D average.

Comment: @MatasSkaržauskas FWIW, one solution is a one-line `for` loop (not nested), using [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).  I would post it, but this looks like homework.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. I'll post it if I manage to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that computes the average of each row using [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
#include <numeric>
//...
B[0] = 0.0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
   B[i] = std::accumulate(A[i], A[i] + i, 0.0) / i;
```

Basically we set the first average to 0.0, since the first row has no values to take the average of.

Then the loop goes through rows 1 to `n`, where we accumulate the values starting from column 0, up to column `i-1`.  Then we take this sum and divide by `i`.  So basically we have this for a 4 row matrix:

```
B[0] = 0;
```

Now the loop:

```
B[1] = (A[1][0]) / 1;
B[2] = (A[2][0] + A[2][1]) / 2
B[3] = (A[3][0] + A[3][1] + A[3][2]) / 3;
```

So the `i` index controls which item in the `B` array to set, which row in `A` we are referring to, and how many items in that row to add, plus what to divide by once all of the items are summed.   The `std::accumulate` does the sum for us by specifying the start and ending range in the row to add, and all we need to do is divide by `i`.

Answer (score 0):

First - n and m should be int's. C++ is smart enough to not give errors in this case, but it's a good practice to separate floating point and integer variables.
Then, I assume you want to use B as output that containts averages. If I'm right, the code should look somewhat like this:

```
double tempsum = 0;
int count = 0;
 for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
    tempsum = 0;
    count = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
         tempsum += A[i][j];
         count++;            
        }
    B[i] = tempsum / count;
    }
}
```